# Assert inequality of two objects having a nested Map field

Tags: java, junit, equals, assert

Iam trying two assert inequality between two objects of the following class type

```
public class CustomDr{
private Map<String,Map<String,Set<String>>> field1;
....
....
@Override
public boolean equals(final Object obj) {

if (this == null || obj == null)
  return false;
CustomDr CustomDr = null;
if (obj instanceof CustomDr) {
  CustomDr = (CustomDr) obj;
}
final Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> appltCustomDrMap1 =
  this.field1;
final Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> appltCustomDrMap2 =
  CustomDr.field1;

for (final String applt : appltCustomDrMap1.keySet()) {
  if (!appltCustomDrMap2.containsKey(applt)) {
    return false;
  }
}

for (final String applt : appltCustomDrMap1.keySet()) {
  final Map<String, Set<String>> productappldCustomDrMap1 =
    appltCustomDrMap1.get(applt);
  final Map<String, Set<String>> productappldCustomDrMap2 =
    appltCustomDrMap2.get(applt);

  if (productappldCustomDrMap1.size() != productappldCustomDrMap2
    .size()) {
    return false;
  }
  for (final String productappld : productappldCustomDrMap1
    .keySet()) {
    if (!productappldCustomDrMap2.containsKey(productappld))
      return false;
  }
  for (final String productappld : productappldCustomDrMap1
    .keySet()) {

    Collections.sort(new ArrayList(productappldCustomDrMap1
      .get(productappld)));
    Collections.sort(new ArrayList(productappldCustomDrMap2
      .get(productappld)));
    if (!productappldCustomDrMap1.get(productappld).equals(
      productappldCustomDrMap2.get(productappld)))
      return false;
  }
}
}
```

Lets asssume i have the following two objects of CustomDr type

```
Obj1
POne|PT2(MN12);PT3(MN13)||PTwo|PT3(MN12);PT4(MN14)

     key value key value       key value key value
key -----value----------  key  ------value--------


Obj2
POne|PT2(MN12);PT3(MN13)||PTwo|PT8(MN15);PT4(MN15)
```

To sum up , i want to know how can i assert intersection of the two Maps as empty ?

Comment: What's wrong with the standard `equals()` method provided by `java.util.Map`?

Comment: There are a couple of things wrong with existing equals method you have provided, actually. For one thing, both `sort` methods do literally nothing, and the whole thing may be achieved by just simple `this.map.equals(other.map)`, dropping majority of your code, as @RobbyCornelissen said. However, your overall intention is not clear. You said that the two objects you given (which are not equal by your definition) are indeed not equal in your test, but you want them to be considered equal? What is the exact requirement there?

Comment: The question is completely unclear. You have two objects that are not equal, and you want them to be considered to be equal because they have one key/value pair that is the same? Are you trying to figure out if the intersection of two maps is empty?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Exactly i want the intersection of two maps to be empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the intersection of two maps by calculating the intersection of their entry sets.

To do this in a non-destructive way (i.e. without altering either of the two maps), you would have to do something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> intersection = new HashMap<>(map1);
intersection.entrySet().retainAll(map2.entrySet());

boolean empty = intersection.isEmpty();
```

In essence, you first create a copy of one of the maps, and then retain only those entries that are also present in the second map. If the result is not empty, that means that there were common elements in both maps.

Here's a complete snippet for you to experiment with:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("POne", new HashMap<>());
map1.get("POne").put("PT2", new HashSet<>());
map1.get("POne").get("PT2").add("MN12");
map1.get("POne").put("PT3", new HashSet<>());
map1.get("POne").get("PT3").add("MN13");
map1.put("PTwo", new HashMap<>());
map1.get("PTwo").put("PT3", new HashSet<>());
map1.get("PTwo").get("PT3").add("MN12");
map1.get("PTwo").put("PT4", new HashSet<>());
map1.get("PTwo").get("PT4").add("MN14");

map2.put("POne", new HashMap<>());
map2.get("POne").put("PT2", new HashSet<>());
map2.get("POne").get("PT2").add("MN12");
map2.get("POne").put("PT3", new HashSet<>());
map2.get("POne").get("PT3").add("MN13");
map2.put("PTwo", new HashMap<>());
map2.get("PTwo").put("PT8", new HashSet<>());
map2.get("PTwo").get("PT8").add("MN15");
map2.get("PTwo").put("PT4", new HashSet<>());
map2.get("PTwo").get("PT4").add("MN14");

Map<String, Map<String, Set<String>>> intersection = new HashMap<>(map1);
intersection.entrySet().retainAll(map2.entrySet());

boolean empty = intersection.isEmpty();

System.out.println(empty); // false
```